# jQuery click function change body overflow property

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a very simple piece of code to change the `body` `overflow` to `hidden` when a pop up fades in.

```
$(".more").click(function() {
    $(".about-pop").fadeIn(1000);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});


$(".close").click(function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
    $(".about-pop").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Related HTML:

```
<div class="about-pop">
   <div class="about-page-text">
    <?php the_field('about'); ?><br><br><img class="close" src="/images/close.png">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="about-intro">
    <div class="about-intro-wrap">
        <div class="about-intro-text"><?php the_field('about_intro'); ?><br><br><img class="more" src="/images/more.png">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My problem is, when the user clicks `.more` the viewport jumps to the top of the html document
so when the user clicks `.close` they are not in the same place. I've used this technique before and never had this problem.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for such questions?

Comment: in short you need a simple popup right..?

Answer (score 0):

in my understanding you have some issue with positioning, so i have added the following styles and it works fine.
let me know if this helps or please clarify your question using jsfiddle.

i have added the following styles

```
 <style>
  .about-pop {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #FFF;
  }

</style>
```

thanks